# Как написать условие при котором 3 переменные не равны друг другу?

Tags: xcode, swift, if

Как написать условие, при котором 3 переменные не равны друг другу?

Есть 3 переменные `hero`, `smoke` и `recycle`.
Мне нужно, чтобы они были все не равны друг другу, т.е. содержали разные значения. Как это описать в условии?

Вот такой код не работает:

```
smoke != hero && smoke != recycle && recycle != hero
```

Comment: что подразумевается под "не работает"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это условие можно записать так.

```
let hero = 0, smoke = 1, recycle = 2
if !(hero == smoke || hero == recycle || smoke == recycle) {
    print("Все 3 переменные не равны друг другу")
} else {
    print("Какие-то из переменных равны друг другу")
}
```

На печать выдаст:

```
Все 3 переменные не равны друг другу
```

Comment: А почему код ТС не работал?)